# History ignores in VIM

Tags: vim

Is there an option similar to Bash's HISTIGNORE to dump some useless lines from the command history (let's say `:wq` or `:help.*`)?

If not, I reckon a simple DIY way would be to parse manually the `.viminfo` file with a regex predicate. Is there a specific VIM linking that could sync the parsing with a change in the `.viminfo` file ?

Comment: You may like the command-line window, `q:`.

Comment: `:help c_Up`: you can also ignore unwanted entries in your history nicely. `:cnoremap <C-p> <Up>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, answer is No. But if you allow put `H` into your typing commands, it maybe possible. How about this?

https://gist.github.com/5864587

```
let g:histignore = '^buf:^history'
function! s:h(commandline)
  call histdel(':', '^H\s')
  let oldhist=&history
  try
    if len(filter(split(g:histignore, ':'), 'a:commandline =~ v:val')) == 0
      call histadd(':', a:commandline)
    endif
    set history=0
    exe a:commandline
  catch
    echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg v:exception | echohl None
  finally
    let &history=oldhist
    unlet oldhist
  endtry
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ H call s:h(<q-args>)
```

Put into this file as your ~/.vim/plugin/h.vim

```
:H buffers
```

This is not stored in `:history`, But

```
:H ls
```

This will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

It causes a tiny bit of lag but this will work:
*(if only there was a `HISTIGNORE` for vim))*

```
augroup StripHistoryOfQAndW
  autocmd!
  autocmd 
  \ CmdLineLeave
  \ * 
  \ echom histdel(":", '^[wq]')
augroup END
```